# Convert python project to one executable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have a **python project** that contains multiple python scripts (5), as well as a database.ini file and a folder within, are the images. I looked around on StackOverflow and google to find any way that could allow me to **convert this whole project to a folder** that contains the dependencies and an **executable** but I can't find anything that fits what I want to do.

Even though python may not be a good choice to make an "app", I can't do it in another way and I really need to be able to **share this project** with someone else without him having to install python or any dependencies by himself.

I found that **pyinstaller** could do it but when I tried, not only I get an error when starting the executable but also, it doesn't read my **requirements.txt** file and installs a hundred useless python libs.

**[EDIT]** : I created a virtualenv in the folder that I want to convert and I activated it. Then I installed only the libs that I needed and I ran this command (in the venv) : `pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --add-data "config.py;." --add-data "database.ini;." --add-data "images;images/"  "app.py"` which creates a dist folder and inside `/dist/app` I have my .exe but not only it still imports all my python modules (more than a hundred) but also I have the following error : `failed to execute script pyi rth win32api`

**[EDIT 2]** : I use Python 3.8 and the only libs used in my whole project are : numpy, pandas, PyQt5 and psycopg2; however pyinstaller also imports matplotlib or tkinter

Thanks!

Comment: @JacobLee See my edit

Comment: `it still imports all my python modules(more than a hundred)` don't worry about that pyinstaller packages everything required for your script to run including the python compiler. If that worries you can use --onefile mode which will package all in a single .exe file.

Comment: I already know that, what I mean is that it imports, for instance, Tkinter or matplotlib even though I don't use these libs.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to use a screen on which to display, I found the following steps to be useful:

First, make sure that whenever importing files, you use this function instead

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    try:
    # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

# example of using it:
img_folder = resource_path('img')
```

Also, add the following to your code:

```
import contextlib

with contextlib.redirect_stdout(None):
    # importing the modules specified in the --hidden-import part of the command, for example Pygame
    import pygame
```

Then, cd in cmd or powershell into the path with the main file in it and run the following: (Write `--hidden-import` for the display module, for example Pygame, and the `--onefile` makes it all in one exe so that it's easier to share with friends).
`python -m PyInstaller --onefile --noconsole Main.py --hidden-import pygame`.

This will create in that same directory two folders and a `.spec` file. In the "dist" folder created, you will find your final exe, but it won't be ready yet:

Enter the `.spec` file, and go into the `datas` section in it - in it, you write which files you import and use in the main file.

For example, you should type something along the lines of `datas=[('maps/*','maps'),('img/*','img')],`

After that, type `python -m PyInstaller Main.spec` in the cmd that's in the same path, and the `.exe` file in the "dist" folder.

It's supposed to only import the modules required - if one of the modules you are using has other modules that it itself is using, then it has to download those too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it doesn't work, check the edit I made to the post to provide more details

Comment: Could you add what your imports are? I think that might help understand both the error and the import issues

Comment: I use Python 3.8 with : psycopg2, pandas, numpy and PyQt5

Comment: There are probably two things going on: First, your 4 modules are importing a lot of other modules, so they must be downloaded too. Second, you might want to try a venv and install only the dependencies you need there. Then, you can make the installer use the venv's installation of python and not your global one.

Comment: I already said in my post that I use a venv in which I run the pyinstaller command and it still installs tkinter or matplotlib even though I never use these modules and they are not necessary for the others to work

Comment: First, you could use --exclude-module for the modules you don't want imported. Second, there might be a chance that one or more of your imported modules are actually using those modules, or that another file in your main folder (or inside it) imports it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [auto-py-to-exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/), I personally use it. With its gui interface it's really easy to use.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, that's why I made this post

Answer (score 0):

for Standalone executable `--onefile` or `-F`

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --add-data "config.py;." --add-data "database.ini;." --add-data "images;images/"  "app.py"
```